# Check if a command has run successfully

Tags: powershell, if-statement

I've tried enclosing the following in an if statement so I can execute another command if this succeeds:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Share -ComputerName $Server.name -Credential $credentials -Filter "Description='Default share'" | Foreach-Object {
        $Localdrives += $_.Path
```

but I can't figure out how to do it. I even tried creating a function but I couldn't figure out how to check if the function had successfully completed either.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

you can try :

```
$res = get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Share -Filter "Description='Default share'"
if ($res -ne $null)
{
  foreach ($drv in $res)
  {
    $Localdrives += $drv.Path
  }
}
else
{
  # your error
}
```

Answer (score 129):

Try the `$?` automatic variable:

```
$share = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Share -ComputerName $Server.name -Credential $credentials -Filter "Description='Default share'"

if($?)
{
   "command succeeded"
   $share | Foreach-Object {...}
}
else
{
   "command failed"
}
```

From [`about_Automatic_Variables`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx):

```
$?
   Contains the execution status of the last command. 
   It contains True if the last command succeeded and False if it failed.
...

$LastExitCode
   Contains the exit code of the last native program or PowerShell script that ran.
```

Comment: I opted for the first solution this time, but this is absolutely a great way to do it. Thanks once again Shay:)

Comment: Sorry Shay : Test 
`get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Share -Filter "Description='glurp'"` , but in this case $? is true and there is no share with this description.

Comment: The command didn't return an error so $? is set to $true. This is the same as: dir *.NoSucheExtension, the result is nothing and is not considered as an error. Use @JPBlanc's solution when you want to test if the the command returned any result.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer since it's more related to the generic question

Comment: PS newbie question: is `"command succeeded"` the same as `Write-Output "command succeeded"` (or some other `Write-*` command)?

Comment: @JoePC "command succeded" is a value returned to the calling part. It's considered bad practice to return more then one value per function call (if put in a function of course).

Answer (score 4):

Or if a failure returns no standard output, that would work for an if statement (*assuming an exception doesn't terminate the pipeline*):

```
if (! (Get-CimInstance Win32_Share -ComputerName $Server.name -Credential $credentials -Filter "Description='Default share'")) { 
  'command failed'
}
```

Also there's now the or symbol "||" in powershell 7 (works with terminating exceptions):

```
Get-CimInstance Win32_Share -ComputerName $Server.name -Credential $credentials -Filter "Description='Default share'" || 'command failed'
```

Comment: Does not work: `if (! (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://does.not.exist") ) { Write-Host "Error!" }`

Comment: @mgutt in that case there's a command terminating exception, so the if statement never runs completely.  The -erroraction silentlycontinue option is also ignored.  You can test that $? is $false afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

There are instances where any of the options are best suitable. Here is another method:

```
try {
Add-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX -RefObjectId (Get-AzureADUser -ObjectID "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX").ObjectId  -ErrorAction Stop
Write-Host "Added successfully" -ForegroundColor Green
$Count = $Null
$Count = 1
}
catch {
$Count = $Null
$Count = 0
Write-Host "Failed to add: $($error[0])"  -ForegroundColor Red
}
```

With try and catch, you don't only get the error message returned when it fails, you also have the $count variable assigned the number 0. When the command is successful, your $count value returns 1. At this point, you use this variable value to determine what happens next.

Answer (score 0):

You can use “$error” automatic variable. This will check if the first command throws error or if it completes successfully.

```
“execute first command”
if($error.count -eq 0)
{
   “execute second command”
}
```

if you want to clear the errors afterwards you can use: `$error.clear()`. This will set the counter of errors to 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
Function CommandStatus ($Status) {
 if ($status -eq $true) {
      Write-Host "Success!" 
    } else {
      Write-Host "Failed!" 
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**