# Catch success and error

Tags: powershell

I want to share this script to block ransom-ware and later share with everyone.
The only point I am stuck at this adding multiple drives and catch error or success when files are created.

What this do is

1. Install FSRM working.
2. Create file screen working something wrong with drives cannot select more than 1.
3. It should catch if files are created so we can say it failed.
4. Catch access denied and say it's working.

Hope someone able to help

```
#Check If FSRM is Are Already Installed
$check = Get-WindowsFeature | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "FS-Resource-Manager"}
if ($check.Installed -ne "True") {
    Install-WindowsFeature -Name FS-Resource-Manager -IncludeManagementTools
} else {
    Write-Host "Cool FSRM is already installed" -F Green
}

#define drive letters here
$drive = @("D:\", "E:\", "C:\users")

#Create notification is required

#$Notification = New-FsrmAction -Type Email -MailTo "[Admin Email];[File Owner]" -Subject "Warning: attempted to create a Ransomeware file text file" -Body "You attempted to create a Ransomeware. This is not allowed." -RunLimitInterval 120

New-FsrmFileGroup -Name "Anti-Ransomware File Groups" -IncludePattern @((Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://fsrm.experiant.ca/api/v1/combined" -UseBasicParsing).Content |
    ConvertFrom-Json | % {$_.filters})

New-FsrmFileScreen -Path "$drive" -IncludeGroup "Anti-Ransomware File Groups" -Active # -Notification $Notification

#test if its working
try {
    New-Item "$drive\$(get-random).xtbl" -Type File -ErrorAction Stop
    Write-Verbose "[RANSOMEWARE CONFIGURATION FAILED] Created $FullName"
} catch {
    $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message 
    Write-Warning "[ERROR] access Denied"
    Write-Host "Congrats you have successfully configured Ransomeware block Sit back and relax"
}
```

Comment: Would Shay Levi's answer in this topic be of use to you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8693675/check-if-a-command-has-successfully-ran

Comment: t dont think so we dont need to use wmi

Comment: Was referring more to the $? being a automatic variable regarding the success fo your previous command,  you didnt check Shay Levi's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

success

```
 $disks = GET-WMIOBJECT win32_logicaldisk -filter "DriveType='3'" | Where {$_.deviceid -ne "C:"}
            ForEach($disk in $disks) {
                                        $DRIVE = $DISK.DeviceID

                                    New-FsrmFileScreen -Path "$Drive\" –IncludeGroup "Anti-Ransomware File Groups" -Active  # -Notification $Notification

                                     }

#Test if its sucess

                                     foreach( $Disk in $disks ) {
                                      $DRIVE = $DISK.DeviceID

Try
    {
      #$newpath=Join-Path -Path $Drive -ChildPath "$(Get-Random).xtbl"
      $File = New-Item "$drive\$(Get-Random).xtbl"-type file -ErrorAction Stop -ErrorVariable 'ErrorMessage'
      Write-host "[RANSOMEWARE CONFIGURATION FAILED] Created $($File.FullName)" -ForegroundColor red
    }

    Catch
    {
        Write-Warning "[ERROR] access Denied"
        Write-Output "File not created: $($File.FullName)"
        Write-Host "Congrats you have successfully configured Ransomeware block Sit back and relax" -f green
    }
    }

   ##### create File screen and block all the shared items


    $paths=Get-WmiObject Win32_Share | Select Name,Path,Type | Where-Object { $_.Type -eq 0 } | Select -ExpandProperty Path

    foreach( $path in $paths ){
New-FsrmFileScreen -Path "$path" –IncludeGroup "Anti-Ransomware File Groups" -Active # -Notification $Notification

}
```