# How to run a .exe file in powershell and write result to Log file

Tags: powershell, exe

I'm looking to run SQLPLUS from powershell. So I want to run a SQLPLUS.exe and then execute a SQL file. Once this runs, if its successful, I want to write to a log file 'This was a success' or 'This was a failure'.

I have tried to run the .exe as

```
 &'path\sqlplus.exe' 'system/password@dbase as sysdba' '@themainscript.sql'
```

but I am finding the next part difficult as to write to the log file if it is a success. I'm not looking to check if it was a success, I need to know how to write to the logfile if it was a success

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if a command has successfully ran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8693675/check-if-a-command-has-successfully-ran) ; I suggest focusing on the most-upvoted answer rather than the accepted one (basically use `$?` that will contain the success value of the previous command)

Comment: Also, to write to a log file `"message" > logPath` seems to be enough. I hardly ever use powershell so it might not be the most idiomatic construct, but I tested it successfully

Comment: @Aaron: It is idiomatic, but a potential gotcha is that `>` creates UTF-16LE files - invariably in v5.0-, and by default in PSv5.1+ (where you can change the encoding with configuration, not ad-hoc). pinkhighlighter: Are you really just looking for `"message" > logPath`?

Answer (score 2):

Easier than transcripting, you can just redirect.

```
& 'command.exe' 'arg' 'arg2' > Logfile.txt
```

If you only want to write on success,

```
$outputofcommand = & 'command.exe' 'arg' 'arg2'
<# logic to check output #>
$outputofcommand > Logfile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at the Start-Transcript command. It has very simple syntax. You just call it passing a file path as argument and then use Write-Host to fill the file. Like this:

```
mkdir C:\Temp
Start-Transcript C:\Temp\logfile.txt
#do something
Write-Host "Success!"
Stop-Transcript
```

Also, you can use the $? variable to determine if the command was succesful or $LASTEXITCODE to get exit code from the process you called (The $? returns true if the exit code was 0).

Note Start-Transcript is useful for more detailed information... If you just want to write "It was succesful", then the redirection is enough: "It was succesful" > "SomeFilePathHere"

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is you only want to log the status of what was run, and not what actually happened?

Provided sqlplus.exe returns an exitcode you can just do this on the line after you run it:

```
if ($?) {add-content "c:\temp\logfile.txt" "This was a success"} else {add-content "c:\temp\logfile.txt" "This was a failure"}
```