# How do you get Windows PowerShell to play a sound after .bat job has finished running?

Tags: powershell, audio, notifications, beep

As the title states, I have a `.bat` job running within PowerShell that when finished running, I would like a sound notification to go off. I was wondering if there was a PowerShell command that I can add to my existing PowerShell command.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you could use powershell automatic variables to check bat file status ..As per  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8693888/2975396),`$?` returns true ,if command is successfull..

below is sample code

```
$a =Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {

& "C:\temp1\test.bat"
}

if($?){

[console]::beep(500,300)

}
```

You could also play custom sounds,

```
$PlayWav=New-Object System.Media.SoundPlayer

$PlayWav.SoundLocation=’C:\Foo\Soundfile.wav’

$PlayWav.playsync()
```

**references:**
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/powertip-use-powershell-to-play-wav-files/

Comment: Note that this does not work if your system sounds are set to silent.

Answer (score 41):

In addition to the solutions @TheGameiswar suggests, you can have some fun by making the system actually speak to you:

```
# Create a new SpVoice objects
$voice = New-Object -ComObject Sapi.spvoice

# Set the speed - positive numbers are faster, negative numbers, slower
$voice.rate = 0

# Say something
$voice.speak("Hey, Harcot, your BAT file is finished!")
```

**Note:** I only tested this on Windows 10, so it may not work on other versions, but give it a go and see.

Comment: It's even more fun when the system knows your name (works on domain, maybe use environment variable for username if not on domain):
`(New-Object -ComObject Sapi.spvoice).speak("Hey, $(([adsi]"LDAP://$(whoami /fqdn)").givenName), your BAT file is finished!")`

Comment: I use it for keeping track of manually started SQL jobs, when I don't want to keep checking console output all the time.

Comment: Loved this, I will be concatenating its execution after all long time running commands :)

Comment: Thanks, but `$voice.speak` will return `1` in powershell. Is there a way to let it return `null`.

Comment: @roachsinai Typically in PowerShell if the cmdlet, method, etc, doesn't have a way of suppressing its output (e.g. `-Quiet` switch), then you use the `Out-Null` cmdlet to discard it.  So, in the example above, change the last line to: `$voice.speak("Hey, Harcot, your BAT file is finished!") | Out-Null`

Answer (score 23):

Besides the excellent solutions of [boxdog](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9529842/boxdog) ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56036054/11942268)) and [TheGameiswar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2975396/thegameiswar) ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56032635/11942268)), I want to mention another possibility, which lets you play some standard system sounds:

```
[System.Media.SystemSounds]::Asterisk.Play()
[System.Media.SystemSounds]::Beep.Play()
[System.Media.SystemSounds]::Exclamation.Play()
[System.Media.SystemSounds]::Hand.Play()
[System.Media.SystemSounds]::Question.Play()
```

---

## Another text-to-speech approach

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Speech
$synth = New-Object -TypeName System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer
$synth.Speak("Hey $env:USERNAME, your job is finished!")
```

### Customization

For full details, read the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer).

#### Voice

Select a voice:

```
$synth.SelectVoice("Microsoft Zira Desktop")
```

You can view available voices with:

```
$synth.GetInstalledVoices() | Select-Object -ExpandProperty VoiceInfo
```

#### Rate

Set the speaking rate from -10 (slow) through 10 (fast):

```
$synth.Rate = 5
```

#### Volume

Set the volume from 0 (quiet) through 100 (loud):

```
$synth.Volume = 75
```