# switch wget from macOS to windows

Tags: windows, macos

I'm using the following script to check if a new file was uploaded to a specific adress on my Mac. gotta switch to a windows PC

Any idea how to have the same function or similar on windows?

while ! wget
https://xxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxx/xx-$
sleep 10
done
afplay /System/Library/Sounds/Funk.aiff
say file found
osascript -e 'tell app "System Events" to display
dialog "Wow.. exciting file downloaded!"'

Answer (score 0):

this is an example in powershell:

```
$var = $true
while($var){
try
{
    $request = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://de.wikipedia.org/favicon.ico" -OutFile "C:\fav.ico"
    [System.Media.SystemSounds]::Asterisk.Play()
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Wow.. exciting file downloaded!","Msg",0)
    $var = $false
}
catch{
Start-Sleep -s 10
}
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-7.2

[How do you get Windows PowerShell to play a sound after .bat job has finished running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56032478/how-do-you-get-windows-powershell-to-play-a-sound-after-bat-job-has-finished-ru)